# Installing window a/c unit

Tags: electrical

Recently we enclosed our garage and finished it off into a bedroom, but it is not cooling well. Since window a/c units are not allowed to be exposed on the exterior of my home, I am considering installing a window a/c unit that I already have to a wall that has an attached storage closet with concrete floors. Therefore, the backside of the window unit would be in this closet. I could put a bucket underneath to catch the condensation and empty regularly.

I'm not sure if this should be a concern, but there is an electric water heater in this same closet that would be about 14' away. Does anyone know if this is a safety concern or am I ok to move forward with this project?

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. How would the heat get out of the closet into the great outdoors?

Comment: All the heat removed from the garage space will be dumped into that closet, are you aware of that and is the closet vented to the outside?

Comment: Along with the heat accumulating in the closet, it must be considered that the temperature can exceed the unit's ability to remove heat from the air and cause failure.

Comment: Consider installation of a "ductless mini-split" a/c or heat pump. This will be a lot more costly than a window unit, but is really the only way to comply with the regulation that no window unit protrude through the exterior wall of the house.

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozaw9QhxkQU

Comment: @JimStewart -- that sounds like an answer

Comment: If your HOA allows it, maybe you can install a window unit and screen it somehow so it's not visible from the street.

Answer (score 3):

Once you jam that closet full of heat, the head pressure will start to climb on the A/C unit. Then the unit will start to go out on high limit.  Then it will just die. The butt end of a wall air conditioner cannot be installed in an enclosed space.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you cannot vent an A/C unit into an enclosed space. Since your HOA prohibits window units, I would suggest a portable A/C -- they exhaust through a relatively inconspicuous vent that fits into a window:

[image: picture of a portable A/C unit]

Comment: Some portable a/c units operate with TWO air hoses. One is intake air for cooling the condenser and the other for the (now heated) outflow air. This solves the problem of the portable lowering the pressure in the room. https://learn.allergyandair.com/portable-air-single-hose-vs-dual-hose/

Answer (score 0):

A free standing in room AC with a duct would be less expensive than a mini split this is what I have suggested for friends in a HOA that don't allow window units. If the home is well sealed a make up air vent will be needed to allow air to enter to replace the exhausted hot air.  Mini splits are coming down in price and would be the most efficient way to heat & cool the area but a bit more expensive than a free standing AC unit with a duct.